# VlookUp: how to loop it?

Tags: dataset, data, excel

I am not an experienced user of Excel because I usually use python but I am obliged to use it this time.

This is the big picture of my case.

The problem is:

I have a sheet with a column with some words, another column with the translation of these words in a non standard written way because they are written using numbers (such as "sale" will be "5413") and they are aligned with the corresponding standard written words (i.e. "sale").

[image: first sheet]

In another sheet I have the same non standard written words (first column) that are sorted from 0 to 9 and there are also some numerical values associated to them.

[image: second sheet]

My goal is:
take the values of the second sheet and put them in the order of the first sheet so that I can have the values of the non standard written words in the same order of the standard written words.

Someone suggested me to use the VlookUp function.

```
=VLOOKUP($D2;$'leet_nopunct (2)'.$2:$1000;**97**;0)
```

It works! But I have to change the second last number (here 97) every time for each column of the second sheet and it is a very long process.

I know that Excel can use some macro: is there a way to loop this number in order to be automatically incremented it?

Comment: Hey, I read the on-topic type of questions. From the help center:
Examples of questions that are likely to be on-topic for Data Science Stack Exchange:

I would like to produce a infographic on the 'Brexit' referendum. Given public opinion data across the UK, what are some meaningful techniques to visaualize it in a dashboard?

It seems that I can also ask for techniques which is my case because I need a technique to do the work automatically. If you disagree let me know and I will place the discussion in Stackoverflow. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`, you can let the desired look up array vary automatically as you drag the function across your columns, which is an alternative to manually fixing the look up column in `VLOOKUP`.

If you wish to continue with `VLOOKUP`, you could potentially add column numbers to the top of your data table, and reference these numbers instead of the hard-coded 97.

Comment: May I ask you for an example to use in this case? I am not really into Excel syntax so I am not sure to have understood what you are saying

Comment: Sure. Assume that the data you are going to be joining data from tab `data_lookup` to data in tab `leet`. Also assume that all data starts in cell `A1`. Then in the tab which contains the leet translations, you can use `INDEX(data_lookup!B$1:B$2,MATCH(leet!$B1,data_lookup!$A$1:$A$2,0)). You will need to change the arrays appropriately, but that's the basic 1-dimension `INDEX-MATCH` combination. This will join the first numeric column on; you will then be able to drag this formula across to join on the remaining 3 numeric columns.